# Joining SQL queries with where clause

Tags: sql, join, where-clause

I have 2 tables in a MYSQL database wich look like this:

Klant:

```
ID  Naam           Email    Soort  Status
6   test           test     test2   
7   status test    test     test    20
8   soort test     test     test    
9   soort test 2   test2    Museum
```

Mail:

```
ID  Content                 Datum       Titel 
1   (lots of encoded HTML)  18-03-13    test
2   (lots of encoded HTML)  18-03-13    test2
4   (lots of encoded HTML)  18-03-13    alles weer testen
```

(yes, I'm still testing alot^^)

Now I have a SQL query that selects all from 'Klant' with a where clause which gets the ID from a previous page:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Klant WHERE ID =  '".$_GET["ID"]."' ";
```

What I want is to JOIN this query with the following query:

```
SELECT ID, Titel FROM Mail;
```

**EDIT:**

From all your answers and comments I think I begin to think my question maybe is totally wrong.. I'll explain where I need it for and I might not even need JOIN? I currently have a table wich includes the data from 'Klant' which looks like this:

[image]

The meaning is that I add another table which includes all the ID's and Title's from 'Mail'. I am sorry for the confusion I may have caused with you since I wasn't that clear with my question. I hope that this may clear up what I want and you guys can maybe tell me if I even need to JOIN this or can I do something else?

I am still a student and this is the first time I've had to use JOIN and I can't figure this out. If anyone can show me how to do this or push me in the right direction it would be great!

Comment: Which columns should be used to perform `JOIN`? I can't see any in your scheme.

Comment: well, to join tables they need to have "information in common". This means, that one table holds a key (primary) that is to be found within the other table as a foreign key. Is this the case in your table structur ( are those IDs linked together) ?

Comment: where is the relationship key between those two tables?

Comment: Perhaps he wants a cross join?

Comment: The ID in the mail table is the identifier for a Mail i assume. What is the identifier for the klant in that table? In other words, how do you know what mail belongs to which klant? I would expect a klant_id columnn or something like that to be present in the mail table.

Comment: You want the klant table expanded with the mail information? e.g `ID|NAAM|EMAIL|SOORT|MAIL_ID|TITEL`. Therefore showing the mail that belongs to a specific klant. This can not be done without a cartesian product unless a proper join column is present in the mail table. All mails will show for each klant without a proper join column.

Comment: Can you show your exact output, what could you expect, that could be useful to us ? which means rough diagram of your exact output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to see how a JOIN is applicable in the example in your question.

A JOIN let's you pull information from more than one table based on a relationship. As far as I can see, your table's don't have any way to link a row in one with a row in the other, unless SteveP is correct and your id's provide that relationship.

For example, if your klant table had a mail_id column then you could do

```
SELECT *
FROM klant
JOIN mail ON klant.mail_id = mail.id
```

and this would return a row for every matching pair of rows in the two tables. Alternatively you could use a LEFT OUTER JOIN to pull back all rows from the table on the left of the JOIN and optionally data from a matching row on the right.

If there is nothing joining the table, you can use a CROSS JOIN which will return you a full cartesian of each row in table1 with every row in table2.

Something people often confuse with a JOIN is a UNION which allows you to write 2 SELECT statements and return the result set of both combined/joined together, but these should return the same columns in each query (e.g. selecting NULL in place of the column in a query if the query doesn't pull data for that column)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM Klant t1
JOIN
SELECT ID, Titel FROM Mail t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
WHERE t1.Name  = 'test'
```

To have the desired result do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM Klant t1
JOIN
SELECT ID, Titel FROM Mail t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

And if you want to have a specific row than just add the where clause:

```
WHERE t1.ID = 6
```

or

```
WHERE t1.Naam = 'test'
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm guess that you want to join on the ID field which is common between the tables.

```
select * from Klant, Mail where Klant.ID = '".$_GET["ID"]."' and Klant.ID = Mail.ID
```

You can also do

```
select * from Klant
  join Mail on  Mail.ID = Klant.ID
  where Klant.ID = '".$_GET["ID"]."'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this directly by using the following query :

```
select k.ID,k.Naam, k.Email,k.Soort,k.Status, m.ID,m.Titel from Klant k, Mail m where k.ID = m.ID and k.ID = '".$_GET["ID"]."'
```